# Android Build from source find - no such file directory Error

Tags: android, build, cyanogenmod

I have been trying to build Cyanogenmod 14.1 from source in Ubuntu 16.04.

When I give the command `brunch device_name`, I am getting an error which has been attached to this question.

Does anyone have the same issue? Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFVr3.png)

```
    make: Entering directory '/home/aswin/android/system'
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
CM_VERSION=14.0-20170430-UNOFFICIAL-
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_Z017
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-72-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NBD90Z
OUT_DIR=/home/aswin/android/system/out
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
find: ‘src/android’: No such file or directory
find: ‘src’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../commonutil/src’: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: cts/tests/libcore/ojluni/resources: No such file or directory
find: ‘../../libs/commonutil/src’: No such file or directory
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/compiler-rt/Android.mk: libcompiler_rt: Unused source files: 






build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/compiler-rt/Android.mk: libcompiler_rt: Unused source files: 

build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/compiler-rt/Android.mk: libcompiler_rt: Unused source files: 




build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/compiler-rt/Android.mk: libcompiler_rt: Unused source files: 




build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/deqp/Android.mk: libdeqp: Unused source files: \
build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/deqp/Android.mk: libdeqp: Unused source files: \
build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/pdfium/third_party/pdfiumbigint.mk: libpdfiumbigint: Unused source files: bigint/BigInteger.cc bigint/BigIntegerUtils.cc bigint/BigUnsigned.cc bigint/BigUnsignedInABase.cc
build/core/binary.mk:1236: external/pdfium/third_party/pdfiumbigint.mk: libpdfiumbigint: Unused source files: bigint/BigInteger.cc bigint/BigIntegerUtils.cc bigint/BigUnsigned.cc bigint/BigUnsignedInABase.cc
external/speex/Android.mk:56: TODOArm64: enable neon in libspeex
build/core/binary.mk:703: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/aswin/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto/frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Format.pb.cc'
build/core/binary.mk:703: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/aswin/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto/frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Format.pb.cc'
build/core/binary.mk:708: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/aswin/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto/frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Format.pb.h'
build/core/binary.mk:708: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/aswin/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto/frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Format.pb.h'
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
find: ‘src/android/bluetooth/client/pbap’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/home/aswin/android/system/out/target/common/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwifi-hal-mock_intermediates’: No such file or directory
find: ‘dummy’: No such file or directory
find: ‘dummy’: No such file or directory
find: ‘dummy’: No such file or directory
hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8937/Android.mk:6: hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8937/legacy/Android.mk: No such file or directory
find: ‘src-N’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../PhoneCommon/src-N’: No such file or directory
find: ‘InCallUI/src-N’: No such file or directory
find: ‘../PhoneCommon/src-N’: No such file or directory
find: ‘dummy’: No such file or directory
find: ‘src’: No such file or directory
find: ‘src’: No such file or directory
system/vold/Android.mk:50: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/aswin/android/system'

#### make failed to build some targets (02:37 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building for a different device.

Comment: No Luck,The Problem Still Exists :(